# span filling width reduced by floating image

Tags: html, css, layout

In my layout I've got some teaser text and an image which is floated to the left so the text flows around it.

Then I have got a "Button" which you can click onto in order to show the complete text.

This "Button" should be displayed below the text and fill the whole width.

This is no problem as long as the text is long enough to wrap below the image so I can use e.g. `display: block` to make it 100% width. But when the text is short I don't find a way to make an element which fills 100% of the **remaining** width.

https://jsfiddle.net/ybtshvqL/

In the website I'm building I use this button with an transparent-to-white background and moved some distance to the top in order to fade the lower part of the text to make it more visual that there is more text available. When using something like a div / block element it always gets drawn 100% of container's width and renders ugly over (or below) the image.

So is there some way to make either a span (`display: inline-block`) 100% width or a div (`display: block`) to honor a float?

(or some other good ideas?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are talking about the "Read on.." button, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix if you are willing to change the `<span>` to a `<div>` tag.

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
   ...
   <div class="more">Read on ...</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.more {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%; /* Or another preferred width percentage */
  margin: auto !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rtkbykbu/

Comment: Hm. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/7n1yjja9/ ? Seems not to work either. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Forked your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bdv64nqh/ and added the missing css. Unfortunately the problem remains the same.

Comment: I am working on it. (Sorry, was riding home from school)

Comment: You mean like this (I don't fully understand your problem)? http://jsfiddle.net/vhete3f9/

Comment: Thanks for your effort! The final thing should look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3tzbnotg/ but it should be working for every text-size. (you can simulate this by moving the separator left/right). ((And it would be nice if it worked without z-index, which is evil.)) ;)